# How to collect value only from scala future result: scala.concurrent.Future[List[String]] = Future(Success(List(10)))

Tags: scala, concurrent.futures

I am having a small Scala code using Future. After execution of code, it returns a String.
My result is coming like below:

```scala
scala.concurrent.Future[List[String]] = Future(Success(List(10)))
```

Here 10 is my return value. How do I get only value 10 and store it in another variable?

Comment: Just think - when can you give the car (which you will buy in future) to your brother. Well... that can happen only in future. So, `val futureCar: Future[Car] = ...` then you can handover this to your brother `val carToBrother: Future[CarToBrother] = futureCar.map(car => giveCarToBrother(car))`.

Comment: Short answer, you can't. - Wrong answer, use `Await.result` - Right answer, a `Future` represents a handler to an ongoing asynchronous operation, you can use the higher-order functions it provides to transform it into something different, like `map` or `flatMap`; that would return a new function that presents applying that callback when the original one finishes, that is the right way to use `Futures`, once you have one your whole codebase becomes `Future` based; waiting is possible to return to a synchronous context but the point of `Future` is not blocking threads, but if you don't care...